# Angularjs unknown provider in $templateRequestProvider

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am including other html files as template in index.html. For this i am using ng-view directive. But i am getting an error:
 `Unknown provider: $templateRequestProvider <- $templateRequest <- $route <- ngViewDirective`
The code I am using is:

```
'use strict';
 var surveyApp = angular.module('surveyApp',['ngRoute']);
    surveyApp.factory('surveyFactory',function (){
 return {}
});
```

Here are the Controllers :

```
surveyApp.controller('profileController', function($scope,surveyFactory) {
    // create a message to display in our view
    $scope.message = 'This is the profile page';
});

surveyApp.controller('surveysController', function($scope,surveyFactory) {
    // create a message to display in our view
    $scope.message = 'This is the surveys page';
});
```

The Config:

```
surveyApp.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
$routeProvider
    .when('/', {    
        templateUrl : 'pages/profile.html',
        controller  : 'profileController'
    })

    .when('/surveys', {
        templateUrl : 'pages/surveys.html',
        controller  : 'surveysController'
    });
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});
```

This is the HTML:

```
<body ng-app="surveyApp">
    <div id="main">
        <div ng-view></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Where am I missing?

Comment: Have you added angular-route.js file ???

Comment: Yes. I have added angular-route.min.js file which loads and no error of any missing scripts is there.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Done. In most of the cases it would be the `versions` of angular-route and angularjs were conflicting. After then, it mostly crashed the page due to continuous loop requests in

```
.when('/', {    
    templateUrl : 'pages/profile.html',
    controller  : 'profileController'
})
```

Every time it saw a '/', it redirected to the same page all over again and hence forming an infinite redirect loop. This should be used in the last so that the first ones are checked, and if something remains, then it sees the '/' route.

Comment: I ran into this error after trying out Angular 1.3 - angular-route 1.3 got served even after a bower install. A bower install -f fixed that.

Comment: Thanks dude, I didn't noticed that bower had installed ngRoute 1.3 although my angular version was 1.2.6

Comment: WOW... Updated from 1.2.n to 1.3.11 -- no error! :)

Comment: Even after updating angular-route to pick correct version it didn't work for some reason.

Comment: Don't update angular-route. Just try to get the versions of the route file and angularjs file same.

Comment: just wasted a complete day on it maaaaan...... thanks a lot for the version conflict info.

Comment: It worked for me too. Its mainly because of version conflict.

Answer (score 4):

Had the same problem, the issue for me was also a dependancy but not angular-route. The dependancy that caused the error for me was angular-bootstrap.

The current angular version in our project is 1.28 and angular-route is also 1.28. This error was triggered on updating angular-bootstrap from 0.12.1 to 0.13.

Comment: Okay, so does that mean that the error still persists on Angular-Bootstrap v0.13 ?

Comment: We didn't explicitly specify our version for bootstrap so it automatically updated to 0.13 and i don't think 0.13 is compatible with angular 1.2*. I don't think this is a problem if you have a later version of angular. These are guesses though.

Answer (score 1):

The only issue with your code is the missing closing curly brace after `surveyFactory` definition.

Change the code for app and factory definition to below to fix the issue:

```
  var surveyApp = angular.module('surveyApp',['ngRoute']);

  surveyApp.factory('surveyFactory',function (){
      return {}
  });
```

Comment: This doesn't help. I used this, but still the same error. I am updating my code. Please check.

Comment: Hmmm... (+1) for the sake of keeping your code clean.