# Unknown provider: $templateRequestProvider <- $templateRequest <- $route <- ngViewDirective

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm just starting with angular.js and I watched some older tuts. where ng-route was not a dependency, so I have changed my code and added  `<script src="js/vendor/angular-route.js"></script>` in html, but I'm getting the same error `Unknown provider: $templateRequestProvider <- $templateRequest <- $route <- ngViewDirective`

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/foundation.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" />
  <script src="js/vendor/modernizr.js"></script>
  <script src="js/vendor/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="js/vendor/angular-route.js"></script>
  <script src="js/vendor/main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div ng-app="app">
    <ng-view></ng-view>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module("app", ['ngRoute']);

app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){
  $routeProvider.when("/",{
    templateUrl: "templates/home.html",
    controller: "AppCtrl"
  }
  );
}]);

app.controller("AppCtrl", function($scope){
  $scope.model = {
    message: "This is my app!!!"
  }
});
```

home.html:

```
<h1>{{model.message}}</h1>
```

Comment: See if this works http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26213627/angularjs-unknown-provider-in-templaterequestprovider?rq=1

Comment: lol I read that 5 times, and after you mentioned I read it again, and just upgrade to latest 1.3.3 and it works.

Comment: ahhh thanks! I randomly grabbed a cdn of angular and grabbed a really old version and never paid attention

Answer (score 1):

I met the issue when using angular-route 1.3.14 and angular 1.2.14 , You need to upgrade angular to version required by angular-route . Here the bower of angular-route 1.3.14 , it require angular 1.3.14.

```
{
    "name": "angular-route",
    "version": "1.3.14",
    "main": "./angular-route.js",
    "ignore": [],
    "dependencies": {
        "angular": "1.3.14"
    },
    "homepage": "https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-route",
    "_release": "1.3.14",
    "_resolution": {
        "type": "version",
        "tag": "v1.3.14",
        "commit": "a405245afdb0f1eac5aad4d8ddc555ed557b3345"
    },
    "_source": "git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-route.git",
    "_target": "1.3.14",
    "_originalSource": "angular-route"
}
```