# Where should i put the html files for angular routing?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
var myapp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngCookies','ui.bootstrap','ngTouch','ui.bootstrap-slider','ngRoute']);
myapp.config(function($interpolateProvider,$locationProvider,$routeProvider) {
$routeProvider.when('/overview', {
               templateUrl: '/mysite/mdm/mdm_overview.html',
               controller: 'AddStudentController'
            }).
            when('/dashboard', {
               templateUrl: '/mysite/mdm/mdm_dashboard.html',
               controller: 'AddStudentController1'
            }).  
           otherwise({
              redirectTo: '/overview'
           });
```

When I run this code following error occurs:

> Unknown provider: $templateRequestProvider <- $templateRequest <- $route <- ngViewDirective

What is the actual problem? Do I need to put the html file inside static folder?

Comment: The error is probably due to libraries version mismatch. Pls verify that the versions of angularjs, router etc are compatible with each other

Comment: Open developers tools in chrome, check the **network** tab - see if you're getting 404 error when loading the templates, or the server return them correctly

Comment: have you included angular-route js?

Comment: Yes i included angular-route js

Comment: Is templateurl has access to django static folder only?@SahilMittal

Comment: DO you have a div that has ng-view ?

Comment: Yes ng-view is there@Giri

Comment: maybe versioning issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27007388/unknown-provider-templaterequestprovider-templaterequest-route-ngvi

Comment: angular-route version is 1.3.14 and angular.js version is 1.2.10.Is this the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to include angular.js and angular-route.js files.
And the files should be in same versions.
angular.js - v1.3.0-rc.5
angular-route.js - v1.3.0-rc.5