# How to debug this AngularJS Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $templateRequestProvider <- $templateRequest <- $route <- ngViewDirective

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-routing

There are a couple questions floating around with the same error, and the common resolution was the angular.js version was out of sync with angular-route.js.

I do not think this is the case with me.

I'm trying to get a demo application running that someone else has written.  I'm getting this error that is not leaving me any clues as to what is going wrong.

```
     Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $templateRequestProvider <- $templateRequest <- $route <- ngViewDirective
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.28/$injector/unpr?p0=%24templateRequestProvider%20%3C-%20%24templateRequest%20%3C-%20%24route%20%3C-%20ngViewDirective
    at angular.js:78
    at angular.js:3801
    at Object.getService [as get] (angular.js:3929)
    at angular.js:3806
    at getService (angular.js:3929)
    at Object.invoke (angular.js:3956)
    at angular.js:3807
    at getService (angular.js:3929)
    at Object.invoke (angular.js:3956)
    at angular.js:5716
```

Is there anything I can do to debug this?

The source code is here:  https://github.com/DataTorrent/malhar-dashboard-webapp

Basically, the routing and a controller is set up like this:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('app', [
    'ngRoute',
    'ui.dashboard',
    'btford.markdown'
  ])
  .config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'template/view.html',
        controller: 'DemoCtrl',
        title: 'simple',
        description: 'This is the simplest demo.'
      })
      .when('/resize', {
        templateUrl: 'template/view.html',
        controller: 'ResizeDemoCtrl',
        title: 'resize',
        description: 'This demo showcases widget resizing.'
      })
      .when('/custom-settings', {
        templateUrl: 'template/view.html',
        controller: 'CustomSettingsDemoCtrl',
        title: 'custom widget settings',
        description: 'This demo showcases overriding the widget settings dialog/modal ' +
          'for the entire dashboard and for a specific widget. Click on the cog of each ' +
          'widget to see the custom modal. \n"configurable widget" has "limit" option in the modal ' +
          'that controls RandomDataModel.'
      })
      .when('/explicit-saving', {
        templateUrl: 'template/view.html',
        controller: 'ExplicitSaveDemoCtrl',
        title: 'explicit saving',
        description: 'This demo showcases an option to only save the dashboard state '+
          'explicitly, e.g. by user input. Notice the "all saved" button in the controls ' +
          'updates as you make saveable changes.'
      })
      .when('/layouts', {
        templateUrl: 'template/layouts.html',
        controller: 'LayoutsDemoCtrl',
        title: 'dashboard layouts',
        description: 'This demo showcases the ability to have "dashboard layouts", ' +
          'meaning the ability to have multiple arbitrary configurations of widgets. For more ' +
          'information, take a look at [issue #31](https://github.com/DataTorrent/malhar-angular-dashboard/issues/31)'
      })
      .when('/layouts/explicit-saving', {
        templateUrl: 'template/layouts.html',
        controller: 'LayoutsDemoExplicitSaveCtrl',
        title: 'layouts explicit saving',
        description: 'This demo showcases dashboard layouts with explicit saving enabled.'
      })
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });
  })
  .controller('NavBarCtrl', function($scope, $route) {
    $scope.$route = $route;
  })
  .factory('widgetDefinitions', function(RandomDataModel) {
    return [
      {
        name: 'random',
        directive: 'wt-scope-watch',
        attrs: {
          value: 'randomValue'
        }
      },
      {
        name: 'time',
        directive: 'wt-time'
      },
      {
        name: 'datamodel',
        directive: 'wt-scope-watch',
        dataAttrName: 'value',
        dataModelType: RandomDataModel
      },
      {
        name: 'resizable',
        templateUrl: 'template/resizable.html',
        attrs: {
          class: 'demo-widget-resizable'
        }
      },
      {
        name: 'fluid',
        directive: 'wt-fluid',
        size: {
          width: '50%',
          height: '250px'
        }
      }
    ];
  })
  .value('defaultWidgets', [
    { name: 'random' },
    { name: 'time' },
    { name: 'datamodel' },
    {
      name: 'random',
      style: {
        width: '50%'
      }
    },
    {
      name: 'time',
      style: {
        width: '50%'
      }
    }
  ])
  .controller('DemoCtrl', function ($scope, $interval, $window, widgetDefinitions, defaultWidgets) {

    $scope.dashboardOptions = {
      widgetButtons: true,
      widgetDefinitions: widgetDefinitions,
      defaultWidgets: defaultWidgets,
      storage: $window.localStorage,
      storageId: 'demo_simple'
    };
    $scope.randomValue = Math.random();
    $interval(function () {
      $scope.randomValue = Math.random();
    }, 500);

  });
```

With the intellij debugger, I've narrowed it down a bit.  It happens after module.config finishes, but before DemoCtrl is ever called.

update 3:
It seems to be crashing inside this function in angular.js:

```
   this.directive = function registerDirective(name, directiveFactory) {
```

when name is "ngView".

Comment: I think some more code would help.

Comment: Can you post some of your code? Make sure your app's module has a dependency on ngRoute - angular.module('<your app>', ['ngRoute']

Comment: Is this a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26213627/angularjs-unknown-provider-in-templaterequestprovider

Comment: Check your versions of angular-router and angular aren't conflicting.