# why my angularJS route doesn't work, chrome'error [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I'm try to use route of angularJS
but it doesn't work
I don't why
**app.js**

```
(function() {
  var todoApp;

  todoApp = angular.module('todoApp', ['ngRoute']);

  todoApp.config([
  ┊ '$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  ┊ ┊ $routeProvider.when('todo/day', {
  ┊ ┊ ┊ template: '<div class="box" ng-class="classname">Edit</div>',
  ┊ ┊ ┊ controller: function($scope) {
  ┊ ┊ ┊ ┊ $scope.classname = "edit";
  ┊ ┊ ┊ }
  ┊ ┊ }).otherwise({
  ┊ ┊ ┊ redirecTo: '/todo'
  ┊ ┊ });
  ┊ }
  ]);

  todoApp.controller('todoCtrl', function($scope) {
  ┊ return console.log(123);
  });

}).call(this);
```

this is html in my app

**.html**

```
  ┊ <div class="five wide column" ng-app="todoApp" ng-controller="todoCtrl">
  ┊ ┊ <div class="ui segment">
  ┊ ┊ ┊ <div ng-view></div>
  ┊ ┊ </div>
  ┊ </div>
```

the console of chrome is here

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $templateRequestProvider <- $templateRequest <- $route <- ngViewDirective  

Error: [$injector:cdep] Circular dependency found: ngViewDirective
```

Comment: This might help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26213627/angularjs-unknown-provider-in-templaterequestprovider

Comment: `ngRoute` module is in separate file, make sure to include it

Answer (score 1):

First of all, make sure you include angular-route.js in your index.html if you haven't done so already.  There is a few mistakes in your script, try it with this if you can.

```
(function() {

var todoApp = angular.module('todoApp', ['ngRoute']);

    todoApp.config(['$routeProvider',
        function($routeProvider) {

            $routeProvider.
            when('todo/day', {
                template: '<div class="box" ng-class="classname">Edit</div>',
                controller: function($scope) {
                    $scope.classname = "edit";
                }
            }).otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/todo'
            });
        }
    ]);

    todoApp.controller('todoCtrl', function($scope) {
        return console.log(123);
    });
}).call(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have to include angular-route.js and make sure you initialized your app modules with ngRoute.

In your html something like:

`<script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>`

Initilize your app with something like:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApplication', ['ngRoute']);
```

Make sure your Routeprovider works properly, I always write it like:

```
myApp.config(function ($routeProvider) {

      $routeProvider
             .when('/', {
                   templateUrl: 'views/mainPages/main.html',
                   controller: 'MainController'
             })
             .when('/news', {
                   templateUrl: 'views/mainPages/news.html',
                   controller: 'NewsController'
             })
             .otherwise({
                   redirectTo: '/'
             });
        })
```

I hope you'll find it helpfull.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run it using server.It is working for me.

To run with eclipse
    `file>new>Dynamic web project>finish
    copy your project files to the web content folder
    run it`