# How do I fix this Angular JS Error: [$injector:unpr]?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Angular JS</title>
    <script src="lib/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/angular-route.min.js"></script>

    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="main" ng-view></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**list.html**

```
<ul class="artistlist">
    <li class="artist cf" ng-repeat="item in artists | filter:artistFilter | orderBy:artistOrder:direction">
        <img ng-src="images/{{item.shortname}}_tn.jpg" alt="{{item.name}}">
        <div class="info">
            <h2>{{item.name|uppercase}}</h2>
            <h3>{{item.reknown}}</h3>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**app.js**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',['ngRoute','artistControllers']);

myApp.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/list', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/list.html',
        controller: 'ListController'
    }).otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/list' 
    });
}]);
```

**controllers.js**

```
var artistControllers = angular.module('artistControllers', []);

artistControllers.controller('ListController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('data.json').success(function(data) {
        $scope.artists = data;
        $scope.artistOrder = 'name'
    });
}]);
```

**full error**

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.9/$injector/unpr?p0=%24templateRequestProvider%20%3C-%20%24templateRequest%20%3C-%20%24route%20%3C-%20ngViewDirective
    at Error (native)
    at http://localhost/angular/lib/angular.min.js:6:449
    at http://localhost/angular/lib/angular.min.js:32:125
    at Object.c [as get] (http://localhost/angular/lib/angular.min.js:30:200)
    at http://localhost/angular/lib/angular.min.js:32:193
    at c (http://localhost/angular/lib/angular.min.js:30:200)
    at Object.d [as invoke] (http://localhost/angular/lib/angular.min.js:30:417)
    at http://localhost/angular/lib/angular.min.js:32:211
    at c (http://localhost/angular/lib/angular.min.js:30:200)
    at Object.d [as invoke] (http://localhost/angular/lib/angular.min.js:30:417)
```

Comment: u have tow angular.module  artistControllers and myApp

Comment: Having two modules shouldn't be an issue. Could you please provide the full error message? My guess is that you load the artistControllers module  after the myApp module. Try placing '<script src="js/controllers.js"></script>' before '<script src="js/app.js"></script>'

Comment: @JanS i wrote full error generated by chrome

Comment: @HumairaNaaz, Angular's error messages might seem misleading at first. This particular error message points at the $templateRequestProvider. You might think "I've never seen nor heard of such a thing" - and you're right. There is no static source for it. What angular is actually missing at this point is the service $templateRequest - give me a sec while I look into its dependencies/module

Comment: I think that as @JanS tell u inject invalid js file.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angularjs unknown provider in $templateRequestProvider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26213627/angularjs-unknown-provider-in-templaterequestprovider)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for providing the error message. Without it, it would have been near impossible to find the error.

I think this might help you:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/26230442/3741957

(There seems to be a version mismatch of angular/ngRoute)

Comment: Looks like.  Works fine with angular 1.4 and ngRoute 1.3.15

Comment: No problem. Just keep in mind that missing $...Provider doesn't necessarily mean that exactly that thing is missing. Makes googling it much easier.

Comment: First result: https://www.google.de/search?q=%24templaterequestprovider&oq=%24templaterequestprovider&aqs=chrome.0.0j69i57j69i61l2.8829j0j4&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=119&ie=UTF-8